# How to run Warp in daemonized mode?

Tags: haskell, haskell-warp

I've been working on a pixel server built using Haskell Warp and have been struggling to work out how to run it in daemonized mode.

Warp works great - I can use `run` from Network.Wai.Handler.Warp to serve HTTP, `runTLS` from Network.Wai.Handler.WarpTLS to serve HTTPS, and I can run both by spawning a new thread:

```
startBoth :: Config -> IO ()
startBoth config = do
  _ <- forkIO $ startHTTPS config
  startHTTP config
```

My problem is figuring out how to use [detachDaemon](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/1.1.1.0/doc/html/System-Daemon.html) from MissingH (System.Daemon) to get my server detached and running in the background on Ubuntu.

In my Main.hs I've tried adding a `detachDaemon` action like so:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  detachDaemon >> cmdArgs options >>= getConfig . optionsConfig >>= start
```

but the program then just silently exits without error, and without anything showing up when I run `ps -ef | grep snowhuskyd`.

How should I be using `detachDaemon` - is it even possible with Warp? I can't find a single example of using `detachDaemon` on the Web - any help would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done some more digging and found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/yesodweb/ERT21ZYUHss/xG6uclkGm9IJ), where a Yesod user (Yesod is the web framework built on top of Warp) asks how to daemonize Yesod using [hdaemoniz](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hdaemonize-0.4.4.1)e (another daemonization lib), and the Yesod/Warp head honcho Michael Snoyman says:

> As an aside, I disagree with the notion that daemonizing is the right
> way to run a process, and think that Upstart (or daemontools, or
> angel, or...) is the correct approach. But I know others have
> different opinions on this.
>
> In other words: I don't think it's something we can fix, and in this
> particular case, I don't think it's worth fixing.

[Angel](https://github.com/jamwt/Angel) from the Bump team looks particularly nice, and it's written in Haskell, so perhaps I should go with that, rather than trying to shoehorn daemonization into my own app.

I'll leave this question open though for now in case people have other ideas!

Comment: I share this point of view, and I detach my daemons from outside. A quick and dirty solution is to use start-stop-daemon, if you have it on your system.